# How to use a trigger to retrieve a combination of some inserted values and deleted values of a raw in a table when an update occur

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a simple table as 'Movie' with the following columns,
mid, title, rating, director.

And also there is a table as Movie_Rating_Updates with the same columns as above.

I want to insert a new raw to the Movie_Rating_Updates table when an update occur to the rating of the movie. In here the record should consists of old 'rating' value and  other values should be new values(if they are also updated with the rating).I want to do it through a trigger.

For an example, suppose I have updated the 'rating' and 'director' of the 'Movie' table where mid=5. Then the trigger should add a new raw to the 'Movie_Rating_Updates' table with mid=5, (title has not updated) and the rating and director values should be the update values.

My problem is how to use a retrieve data from two tables (from  INSERTED table and DELETED table) by using a trigger.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER update_rating ON Movie
 FOR UPDATE
 AS
 BEGIN
 IF UPDATE(rating)
 INSERT INTO Movie_Rating_Updates(mid,title,rating,director)
 SELECT......
```

I have no idea how to write the remaining part of the trigger.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I don't have time to answer now, but if you google "sql server inserted and deleted tables" you will get loads of results, with many examples of how to use them.

Comment: okay thank you,I'll try then